# Boruta Algorithm for Logistic Regression?

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection, regression-strategies, boruta

Is it okay to use a Boruta algorithm to select features for a logistic regression?

I read several sources, including the [source package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Boruta/Boruta.pdf) as well as this [site](https://blog.exploratory.io/finding-variable-importance-with-random-forest-boruta-28badd116197) explaining what Boruta does. My understanding is that it basically takes existing variables, creates a new 'shadow' column with those variables shuffled in a random order, and then performs a random forest and calculates the variable importance of a Random Forest. Variables that are below the best 'shadow' variable are considered bad, and variables that are relatively close in score to the best 'shadow' variable are considered tentative. It does this many times to get the overall selected features.

I'm wondering if such a method would be okay to use for a logistic regression. Thanks!

Comment: What is your goal in fitting the logistic regression? If your goal is inference, I could see this messing with the p-values and confidence intervals like stepwise regression does.

Comment: The ultimate goal is prediction. However, I think that in doing so, the methodology towards getting the end result must have some kind of valid justification. I think that the Boruta seems powerful, but it seems difficult to justify, since I am using a variable importance metric over and over again to select features for a logit model.

Comment: @Dave Stepwise regression on basis of p-values or AIC is a greedy algortihm that wil select a suboptimal feature set. The point of Boruta is that it is a Monte Carlo algorithm that searches randomly and thus can find a solution closer to the global optimum. Side note: I do not think that p-values are a good criterion for variable selection in logistic regression, because they are not even loosely related to importance in logistic regression due to its non-linear nature.

Comment: I have had good to exceptional results using Boruta to find "important" columns, then using only those with another model.  Mileage varies, and you have to know what you are doiing.